# Am I on the right track? Any hints on what to do next?

Tags: calculus

I am proving 13.16(a) of Spivak which states.

> Given $f$ is an increasing function, and given a partition $P = \{ t_0, \ldots , t_n \}$ and $P' = \{ f^{-1}(t_0), \ldots , f^{-1}(t_n) \}$, both on $[a,b]$. Prove: $$ L(f^{-1}, P) + U(f, P') = bf^{-1}(b) - af^{-1}(a)$$ where $L$ is the lower sum function, and $U$ is the upper sum function.

So we have:

$$L(f^{-1}, P) = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i ( t_i - t_{i-1} ) $$

$$U(f, P') = \sum_{i=1}^n M_i ( f^{-1}(t_i) - f^{-1}(t_{i-1}) ) $$

Now let $y = f^{-1}(x)$:

$$ f(y) = x $$

Since $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and we know $f'(y) > 0$ since $f(y)$ is increasing, then $f^{-1}(x)$ is increasing. Now $L$ becomes the LHS and $U$ becomes the RHS. Thus, $L(f^{-1}, P) + U(f, P')$ becomes:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(t_{i-1})(t_i - t_{i-1}) + \sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i)(f^{-1}(t_i)-f^{-1}(t_{i-1}) ) $$

I don't know if I made a mistake, and don't know what to do from here. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up the minima and maxima of $f$ and $f^{-1}$.

Since $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both increasing one  has
$$L(f^{-1},P)=\sum_{k=1}^n f^{-1}(t_{k-1})(t_k-t_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^n t_{k-1}'(t_k-t_{k-1})$$
and
$$U(f,P')=\sum_{k=1}^n f(t'_k)(t_k'-t_{k-1}')=\sum_{k=1}^nt_k(t_k'-t_{k-1}')\ .$$
Adding the right hand sides up one gets a lot of cancellation, so that only
$$L(f^{-1},P)+U(f,P')=t_n t_n'-t_0t_0'=b f^{-1}(b)-a f^{-1}(a)$$
remains.

Comment: Darn it! Silly mistakes, I get it now, ends up being: $\sum_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(t_i)t_i - f^{-1}(t_{i-1})t_{i-1}$ which telescopes (I believe that is the right term) and gives the correct result. Thanks! (Although, I do believe my lower sum was correct.)